# How do I restore a deleted multi-image

Tags: codenameone

I accidentally deleted a multi-image entry from the list in the Codename One theme designer and can no longer access the image from code (I get a NullPointerException) or the Designer & GUI Editor. The folder with the scaled images is still located in the res/theme folder for the project.

I would like to restore this entry in the list but every option I can find to add a multi (or any) image doesn't seem to be able to handle this case. How can I add a multi-image folder to the resource list?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Netbeans 8.1

Comment: If there is a solution that does not involve XML Team Mode it would be more helpful in this particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to solve this:

1. Cut that multi-image folder and paste somewhere out of the res folder.
2. In your theme designer, add a dummy multi-image and rename it to match your required multi-image's name.
3. Save your theme designer and close it, now go to your res folder and delete the newly created multi-image folder that matches the name of the original one and copy the previous one you paste somewhere into the folder.
4. Open your `theme.res` and save again.

**EDIT:** 
Second method:

Check `XML Team Mode` under `File` in your theme designer, close the designer without saving anything.

Make sure your multi-image folder is located in the res folder. Go to Netbeans and switch the projects navigation tab to `Files` and look for `theme.xml` under your project files tree and double click to edit, now add the below code right after `<resource majorVersion="1" minorVersion="7" useXmlUI="false">`

```
<image name="my-image-name.png" type="multi"  />
```

Substitute your image name as necessary. Save the xml file and close it, then reopen your theme.res and change anything just to create a new "Save" .

Comment: This does not work. The "dummy" image remains in the list.
1) I believe that the images that are actually used in the app are stored in the res file itself, not in the folders.
2) When I added the dummy image, no new folder was created to replace the one I moved out.

I wonder if there was a change in latest update that causes the designer not to create a multi-image folder in res/theme

Comment: In that case, check `XML Team Mode` under `File` in your theme designer before saving. Then start all over.

Comment: Ah. I had to disable XML team mode due to another bug with the round borders in the designer. My theme will not load in XML Team Mode until the bug is fixed. So this solution will not work.

Comment: I got a workaround to make the theme load properly in XML Team Mode. This solution was successful once that was in place. Although I wish there was a way to do it from within the Designer.